# EFS volume bind auto detaching/reattaching on every `terraform apply` for ECS task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-efs

I am currently using AWS ECS for my service deployment. For the shared volumes, I am binding some EFS volumes.

Here is my task definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs-fargate" {
  family                   = var.ecs_task_definition_name
  container_definitions    = var.container_definitions
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu                      = var.ecs_task_cpu
  memory                   = var.ecs_task_memory
  execution_role_arn       = var.ecs_task_execution_role_arn
  task_role_arn            = var.ecs_task_role_arn

  dynamic "volume" {
    for_each = var.volumes
    content {
      name = volume.value["name"]
      efs_volume_configuration {
        file_system_id     = volume.value["file_system_id"]
      }
    }
  }
}

var "volumes" {
default = [
    {
      name           = "vol1"
      file_system_id = "fs-xxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
      name           = "vol2"
      file_system_id = "fs-xxxxxxxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

The Terraform code above is working fine as well.

But when I do the `terraform apply` every time, the task definition detaches the EFS volume first and re-attach the same again. Here is the screenshot of the issue:

```
     - volume {
          - name = "vol1" -> null

          - efs_volume_configuration {
              - file_system_id          = "fs-xxxxxxx" -> null
              - root_directory          = "/" -> null
            }
        }
      + volume {
          + name = "vol1"

          + efs_volume_configuration {
              + file_system_id     = "fs-xxxxxx"
              + root_directory     = "/"
            }
        }
```

Am I missing some additional Terraform configuration here for the above issue?

Comment: Is the filesystem ID definitely the same on each run? You shouldn't need to censor that but doing so adds some ambiguity to your question.

Comment: Hi @ydaetskcoR, I have checked and confirmed that they will be same on each apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `apply` your TF config you should see that **no changes are actually performed**. If you check TF docs for [efs_volume_configuration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition#efs_volume_configuration) you will see that it has number of attributes. Some of them will be **default**, such as your `root_directory` which you don't specify. TF may need to pick up those default values after your initial `apply`. Thus later you may seem them in your subsequent `terraform plan`.

Answer (score 0):

**suggestion:**
first of all you should follow their standard practices of avoiding dynamic blocks whenever possible, if there are handful of items, dont use it. last paragraph for reference https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html .

**solution1:**

taking partial idea from @marcin's answer, it seems that default mount point is `/` in docs, so change the mount points of 2 different EFS volumes to lets say `/vol_a` and `/vol_b`, as there is a race condition for mountpoint at `/`.

**solution2:**

rewrite  Terraform configuration without using `dynamic` language expression.
extending the suggestion above, using `fs-xxxxxxxx` for both is very ambiguous, either you couldve mentioned `fs-yyyyyyyy` for second EFS volume id. they are not ip addresses to be censored, and cant be accessed outside your VPC. so relax.